# I am trying to get images from my backend api. But i am not able to perform that.please help me

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to upload a image along with its details. but i can get the all details but only the image is not displaying in the browser. i used php laravel for backend api. The images are located in the Storage/app/apiDocs folder in backend laravel. the i write displayBooks function the get all the books in laravel. But in front end only image is not displaying. Here is a screenshot of output.[image: screenshot]

screenshot of inspect elements.[image: screenshot]
`DisplayBooks.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="bookdisplay-section">
    <div class="book" v-for="book in books" :key="book.id">
        <div class="image-section">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img v-bind:src="book.file" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="name-section">
            {{book.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="author-section">
            by {{book.author}}
        </div>
        <div class="price-section">
            Rs. {{book.price}}<label>(2000)</label>
            <button v-if="flag" type="submit" @click="handleSubmit();Togglebutton();">close</button>
        </div>
        <div class="rating">
            <p>4.5<i class="fas fa-star"></i></p>
        </div>
        <div class="quantity">
            <p>(20)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import service from '../service/User'
export default{
    name: 'DisplayBooks',
    data(){
        return{
            flag: true,
            books: [{
                id: 1,
                file: 'display image',
                name: 'Dont make me Think',
                author : 'Joseph',
                price : '1500',
            },]
        }
    },
    methods:{
        Togglebutton(){
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handleSubmit(){
            service.userDisplayBooks().then(response => {
                this.books.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/Styles/DisplayBooks.scss";
</style>
```

`FileController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
// use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\Books as BooksResource;
use App\Models\Books;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    
    public function displayBooks()
    {
        $books=Books::all();
        return User::find($books->user_id=auth()->id())->books; 
    }

    function upload(Request $request){
        $book = new Books();
        $book->price=$request->input('price');
        $book->name=$request->input('name');
        $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
        $book->author=$request->input('author');
        $book->description=$request->input('description');
        $book->file=$request->file('file')->store('apiDocs');
        
        $book->user_id = auth()->id();
        $book->save();
        return ["result"=>$book];
        // return [$book];        
    }


    public function updateBook(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $book = Books::find($id);
        if($book->user_id==auth()->id()){
            dd($request->all());
            $book->price=$request->input('price');
            $book->name=$request->input('name');
            $book->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
            $book->author=$request->input('author');
            $book->description=$request->input('description');
            // $book->file=$request->file('file')->store('apiDocs');
            $book->save();
            return[$book];
            
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => ' Book is not available with this id'], 404);
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm going crazy trying to figure out what your `displayBooks` method actually does. Could you explain please?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your `displayBooks` but anyway, could you provide value of one of `src` attributes? using inspect element

Comment: Hello @MrEduar...This displayBooks function is used for getting all books based on user_id...the books are created through upload function.

Comment: Hello @MohammadMirsafaei..in inspect elements also it's coming but it's not getting reflected in dashboard. I am editing my post and give the inspect screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Images will only be visible if the visibility of the file is set to public. The best practice here is to upload the image to the Public disk (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk). Make sure to create the symoblic link using `php artisan storage:link`.

This means you should change your upload function as well, to something like:

```
$request->file('file')->store('fileName', 'public');
```

In case this project will be made publicly available, consider adding Request validation to the store/update functions.